# Copy list of files to list of folders one-to-one in R

Tags: r, file, copy, one-to-one

In R, I need to copy the files listed in a vector into the folders listed in another vector in a one-to-one correspondence.

In the example below, I want `sc1.png` to be copied into the `test1` folder and `sc2.png`  into the `test2` folder.

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
files <- c("~/Desktop/test/sc1.png", "~/Desktop/test/sc2.png")
dirs <- c("~/Desktop/test/test1", "~/Desktop/test/test2")

file.copy(files, dirs)
```

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Attach the filenames to `dirs`, you can use `basename` to get the filename.

```
file.copy(files, paste0(dirs, '/', basename(files)))
```